# Sequence numbers for varchar data type?

Tags: oracle11g

This is used to generate for integer data type

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence
       [INCREMENT BY n]
       [START WITH n]
       [{MAXVALUE n | NOMAXVALUE}]
       [{MINVALUE n | NOMINVALUE}]
       [{CYCLE | NOCYCLE}]
       [{CACHE n | NOCACHE}];
```

I want to genrate a sequence id of varchar data type.

Sequence numbers for varchar data type?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: What would such a 'sequence number' sequence look like?

Comment: Tanx for the rply.Like driving licene or pan card number which is a combination of both Characters and numbers??

Comment: There's no built-in mechanism, aside from GUIDs. You need to define your requirement properly - figure out the exact format you want, how you would create/increment values manually, and then maybe see if you could encode a numeric sequence. In a simple form, for example, converting to base 16 would give you a string, but it sounds like you want comething rather more complex.